# Trying To Capture a message into a text or xml file before it goes through orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm troubleshooting an issue wherein two XML elements are missing in the outgoing message.

I have the following relatively simple Orchestration:

```
Receive Port  -> Orchestration -> Send Port (IBM MQ)
```

I want to inspect the message before it goes through the orchestration, to see if the incoming message is a problem. To do this, I created an additional Send Port, with `FILE` type transport (I call it `DefectTroubleshootingSendPort`), and `PassThruTransmit` for Send Pipeline.

The URI for this port is : 
`C:\temp\Defect986\%MessageID%.xml`

I set the Filter for this Send Port as

`BTS.ReceivePortName == "OrderManagement.MembershipActivityExport.ReceivePort"`

I added this new port and the original MQ Send Port to a Send port Group and bound this group to the Outbound Logical Port of the Orchestration.

Even after this, I don't see the temp file getting written at all. The message however goes to the MQ.

Am I doing this right, or is there any better way to capture the incoming message? Do I even need a filter here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply stop the orchestration, but keep it enlisted. When a message comes in, an orchestration instance will spawn but sit in a Suspended (resumable) state, allowing you to view its messages.

Answer (score 1):

To allow you to do what you wanted to do:

- Enable tracking on the incoming receive port. You might want to use `XmlReceive`, since the `PassThruReceive` pipeline tracking might not be enabled by default.
- After you enabled it, check the `Tracked Message Events` hub page and see what properties were tracked. You can find if the receive port name/property was written to the message there AND (important!) if it is promoted.

If the receive port property is promoted, check if the filter is correct. I assume your filter is incorrect to be honest.